# ayuda por favor con este error!

Tags: mysql, netbeans

He tratado todo y no logro resolverlo, es un Dao impementation, en la linea 148 que dice

> private DaoImpl Cliente_Dao_Impl(int ultid) {
>           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
>       }

Les dejo mi código completo, ojala me puedan ayudar

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DaoImpl;

import Conexion.Conexion;
import Dao.Dao_Cliente;
import Idao.Interface_ClienteDao;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Lorena
 */
public class Cliente_Dao_Impl extends Conexion implements Interface_ClienteDao{

    @Override
    public void registrar(Dao_Cliente cliente) {

        try {
            this.conectar();
            String sql="INSERT INTO cliente values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,0)";
            PreparedStatement st = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
            //st.setString(1, null);
            st.setInt   (1, cliente.getId_cliente());
            st.setString(2, cliente.getUsuario());
            st.setString(3, cliente.getPassword());
            st.setString(4, cliente.getNombre_cliente());
            st.setString(5, cliente.getApe_pat_cliente());
            st.setString(6, cliente.getApe_mat_cliente());
            st.setString(7, cliente.getDireccion_cliente());
            st.setString(8, cliente.getTelefono_cliente());
            st.setInt   (9, cliente.getEstado_cliente());
            st.setString(10, cliente.getRut_cliente());

            st.executeUpdate();

            st = con.prepareStatement("select MAX(id_cliente) from cliente");
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = st.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                String last = rs.getString(1);


            String sqllogin="INSERT INTO login values(null,?,?,?,0)";
            PreparedStatement stlogin = this.con.prepareStatement(sqllogin);
            //st.setString(1, null);
            int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(last);

            stlogin.setInt(3, numEntero);
            stlogin.setString(1, cliente.getUser());
            stlogin.setString(2, cliente.getPass());
            stlogin.setInt(3, numEntero);


            stlogin.executeUpdate();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Dao_Cliente> obtener() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void actualizar(Dao_Cliente cliente) {

        try {
            this.conectar();
            String sql="UPDATE cliente SET usuario=?, password=?, nombre_cliente=?, ape_pat_cliente=?, ape_mat_cliente=?,direccion_cliente=?,telefono_cliente=? WHERE rut_cliente=?, estado_cliente=?, id_cliente=?";
            PreparedStatement st = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);

            st.setInt(1, cliente.getId_cliente());
            st.setString(2, cliente.getUsuario());
            st.setString(2, cliente.getPassword());
            st.setString(3, cliente.getNombre_cliente());
            st.setString(4, cliente.getApe_pat_cliente());
            st.setString(5, cliente.getApe_mat_cliente());
            st.setString(6, cliente.getDireccion_cliente());
            st.setString(7, cliente.getTelefono_cliente());
            st.setInt(8, cliente.getEstado_cliente());
            st.setString(9, cliente.getRut_cliente());



            st.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void eliminar(Dao_Cliente cliente) {

          try {
                  this.conectar();
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
            String sql="UPDATE cliente SET estado_cliente=1 WHERE rut_cliente=?";

            int confirmar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Esta seguro que desea eliminar el registro?");


            if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION==confirmar) { 

             Connection conexion = null;

            PreparedStatement st = null;
                  try {
                      st = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
                  } catch (SQLException ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Dato Eliminado");
                  try {
                      st.setString(1, cliente.getRut_cliente());
                  } catch (SQLException ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }


                  try {
                      st.executeUpdate();


                 }catch (Exception ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }  


    private DaoImpl Cliente_Dao_Impl(int ultid) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public List<Dao_Cliente> obteberultimoid() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean buscarcliente(Dao_Cliente cliente) {
          try {
            this.conectar();
            String sql="select * from cliente WHERE rut_cliente=?";
            PreparedStatement st = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);

            st.setString(1, cliente.getRut_cliente());
             ResultSet rs;
            rs = st.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){


                cliente.setId_cliente(rs.getInt("id_cliente"));
                cliente.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));
                cliente.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                cliente.setNombre_cliente(rs.getString("nombre_cliente"));
                cliente.setApe_pat_cliente(rs.getString("ape_pat_cliente"));
                cliente.setApe_mat_cliente(rs.getString("ape_mat_cliente"));
                cliente.setDireccion_cliente(rs.getString("direccion_cliente"));
                cliente.setTelefono_cliente(rs.getString("telefono_cliente"));
                cliente.setEstado_cliente(rs.getInt("estado_cliente"));
                cliente.setRut_cliente(rs.getString("rut_cliente"));
            }


     return true;
              }catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente_Dao_Impl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return false;

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private DaoImpl Cliente_Dao_Impl(int ultid) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Esto el codigo que se genera automaticamente, asi como esta siempre que lo invoques te dara ese error porque esta programado para responder asi. Tendrias que editar lo que esta dentro para que haga en especifico como por ejemeplo en "buscarcliente".

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he podido solucionar

Comment: @lorena Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada.